# Twilio unable to send recorded voicemail to SMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I created a simple call screener using Twilio Studio Flows.

**How it works:**

1. Someone calls my Twilio number
2. A greeting is played
3. If they hang-up or record audio

- Twilio sends a SMS text, with the audio recording URL, to my actual phone number
- The `Media URL` value is `{{widgets.RECORD_VM.RecordingUrl}}` according to [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/record-voicemail#record-voicemail-variables)

**Visual:**

[image]

**Problem:**

- Most of the time, the Flow fails with [ERROR - 11200](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200)

[image]

- If I drill into one of the errors and **replay** the request, the audio recording is returned.

[image]

- It feels like there needs to be a pause between the time the `RECORD_VM` step and `SEND_SMS` steps in the Flow.
- Some pause to give Twilio time to write the audio recording to a database so it can be retrieved by the `SEND_SMS` step.
- But it I don't see an option for this in Flow.

**How should I troubleshoot and address this?**

Answer (score 1):

The fix ended up being:

- Move `{{widgets.RECORD_VM.RecordingUrl}}` from the `MEDIA URL` field to the `MESSAGE BODY` field as shown.
- (Thanks to Akash @ Twilio Support!)

[image]